# Simplify an expression with a root $ \frac{\sqrt{-x+2}}{\sqrt{x-1}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify an expression with a root

I don't understand a transformation.

For this, $f_n= \frac{n}{2}l_n\sqrt{1-l_n^2/4}$

And now I'd like to show that

$\frac{1}{1-l_{2n}^2/4}f_{2n}=\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-l_n^2/4}}\cdot\frac{n}{2}l_n$

holds

Can anyone help me?

According to my calculations

$f_{2n}=\frac{2n}{2}l_{2n}\sqrt{1-l_{2n}^{2}/4}$ and then

$\frac{1}{1-l_{2n}^2/4}\frac{2n}{2}l_{2n}\sqrt{1-l_{2n}^2/4}=n\frac{l_{2n}\sqrt{1-l_{2n}^2/4}}{1-l_{2n}^2/4}=n\cdot l_{2n}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-l_{2n}^2/4}}=\frac{n}{2}\cdot l_{2n}\cdot \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-l_{2n}^2/4}}$

Also we have

$l_{2n}^2=l_n^2/4+\big(1-\sqrt{1-l_n^2/4}\big)^2=2\big(1-\sqrt{1-l_n^2/4}\big)$

So I substituted the expression $l_{2n}$, but I can't prove the desired formula.

After putting in $n\cdot l_{2n}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-l_{2n}^2/4}}$ I got

$n\sqrt{2\big(1-\sqrt{1-l_n^2/4}\big)}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(2\big(1-\sqrt{1-l_n^2/4}\big))/4}}=n\frac{\sqrt{2\big(1-\sqrt{1-l_n^2/4}\big)}}=n\frac{\sqrt{2\big(1-\sqrt{1-l_n^2/4}\big)\sqrt{1-l_n^2/4}\big)}}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{1-l_n^2/4}-1}}=n\frac{\sqrt{-2\sqrt{1-l_n^2/4}+2}}{\sqrt{2\sqrt{1-l_n^2/4}-1}}$

Now I don't know how I can further simplify the Expression.

Comment: Can you edit your post to make it more clear, please? For example, what is $l_n$?

Comment: How does $l_{2n}$ relate to $l_n$?  We can say *anything* about an expression using $l_{2n}$ is compared to an expression without $l_{2n}$.

Comment: @simonet $l_n$ is the length of a equilateral triangle, it was a Problem dealing with Polygons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing will be changed if you bring both the numerator and denominator under a single radical and bring the twos inside the radical to obtain

$$ n\sqrt{\frac{2-\sqrt{4-l_n^2}}{\sqrt{{4-l_n^2}}-1}} $$
Then the fraction under the radical can be rationalized.

$$ n\sqrt{\frac{2-\sqrt{4-l_n^2}}{\sqrt{{4-l_n^2}}-1}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{{4-l_n^2}}+1}{\sqrt{{4-l_n^2}}+1}}=n\sqrt{\frac{l_n^2-2+\sqrt{4-l_n^2}}{3-l_n^2}} $$

Although you could rationalize the denominator, I would not take it any further.